# cannot connect to SQL Server using local 127.0.0.1 address unless the login user has sysadmin role

Tags: sql-server, permissions, connectivity, connection-string

### problem

i am trying to connect to the server using `Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` through `sqlcmd` setting the `-S` (server) option pointing at `127.0.0.1,1434`. i have confirmed this is the correct port.

i cannot use the traditional `.`, `(local)`, `localhost` options. **it must address the server by its loopback interface IP `127.0.0.1`** (see end of post for additional context of why).

> **TLDR: why can i only connect over the local IP `127.0.0.1` when the login has `sysadmin` role?**

### what i have tried

when i connect using a login (`local`) that has the `sysadmin` role it works:

```sh
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1,1434 -U local -P **** -d ****
1>
```

however i am trying to connect through a new login i created that has more restricted access . therefore i do not want to give this new login the `sysadmin` role and instead it is using the default `public` role.

when i try to connect the same way with this login i get `Login failed for user 'TestLogin'`

```sh
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1,1434 -U TestLogin -P **** -d ****;
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'TestLogin '..
```

i am trying to understand why `sysadmin` role somehow allows "remote" (all local on the host machine) access but without this role it fails.

### root cause

the root cause is that `sysadmin` role is required to connect over `127.0.0.1`. i cannot find any information why this is the case.

### Full Context

my end goal is to be able to connect to the server from a containerized process using SQLALchemy/PyODBC. in this configuration i use `host.docker.internal` to access the host `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`).

**i am able to establish the connection using the `local` (with `sysadmin` role) login from inside the container without issue.** however, when using the more restricted login it fails.

so i tried to isolate the issue by attempting from outside the container and just calling sqlcmd directly from powershell on the host machine. as you can see from the original question i am having the same issue so it is not related to being in the container.

i provide this extra context because from the container i cannot use the traditional `.`, `(local)`, `localhost` options. **it must address the server by its loopback interface IP `127.0.0.1` since this is proxied to the container through `host.docker.internal`**

Comment: Look at the errorlog for SQL Server, there will be a login failure (18456), what's the state and the reason?

Comment: Have you tried port 1433 instead of 1434? TCP 1434 is usually the default port for Dedicated Admin Connections, requiring sysadmin.

Comment: @SeanGallardy where can i view those?

Comment: @DanGuzman wow that could be it man! i thought that guy who configured the machine before had just set the regular connection to that port. when i ran the query suggested in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19452652/19832958) i saw 1434 and tried it

Comment: @DanGuzman that solved it man! i had to use sql server configuration manager and enable the 127.0.0.1 IP address (active + enabled) on port 1433. if you want to post as an answer i can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TCP 1434 is usually the default port for Dedicated Admin Connections, requiring sysadmin. That explains why the connection succeeds with a sysadmin role member but fails with a minimally privileged login.

If you haven't already done so, enable port 1433 on the 127.0.0.1 loopback IP using [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver16). You should then be able to connect without sysadmin role membership. Also, since 1433 is the SQL Server default port, an explicit port specification is not required.

Comment: thank you again dan. this got it all sorted out. hopefully this helps someone else in the future